# Activate Firebase Events DebugView in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Is there any way to activate the [Firebase Events DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) in Unity or even just to log an event without the use of a real/virtual device (use it with a PC application)?

I can use [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/), [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) and the [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start) with no problem, but when I try to use the [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start) to Log events, nothing happens.
I've even tried the [quick-start sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/analytics/testapp) with no success.

Is it possible or I can only use it with a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase very few services only support Desktop/Editor version. Unfortunately  Analytics will not support it. you need to build on device and debug in Xcode/Android studio

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup - please see last 2 paragraph

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how I missed it.. I've read until the "Supported Firebase services", but not the one specifically to desktop. Thank you again!